# Sending data using USB CDC (STM32)

Tags: c, stm32, adc, nucleo, stm32cubeide

---

I'm using NucleoF413ZH and STM32CubeIDE. I have 16 microphones, each connects to one ADC channel and thanks to the use of DMA it directs data to the memory. However, I would like to do a cross-correlation of the signals, so I came to the conclusion that I would send the data to the PC or RPi 4b, and I would do the calculations there. But the problem for me is sending so much data from the memory. I try to use CDC_TRANSMIT_FS but I cant send all 16 channel measurements, also transmision is very slow.
Is there any way to send whole array of 16 elements, or even better 16xM elements, so maybe it will be faster? I need 16mic x10bit x44.1khz ~= 7Mbit/s =882KBytes/s, also i can reduce some mics to 12 of them. Here is my code (full in link https://pastebin.pl/view/6059edc8 ):

---

Also, sorry if something is not good grammatically, English is my second language and I'm still learning

---

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint16_t Pomiar[16]; // measurments 16x1
char msg[10];

uint8_t DataToSend[40]; // 
uint8_t MessageCounter = 0; //
uint8_t MessageLength = 0; // Msg lngth
/* USER CODE END PV */
```

---

```
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint16_t*)Pomiar, 16);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {

    // CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)Pomiar, (512));

        //++MessageCounter;
        //MessageLength = sprintf(DataToSend, "Wiadomosc nr %d\n\r", MessageCounter);
    //  MessageLength = sprintf(DataToSend, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d\n\r", Pomiar[0],Pomiar[1],Pomiar[2],Pomiar[3],Pomiar[4],Pomiar[5],Pomiar[6],Pomiar[7],Pomiar[8],Pomiar[9],Pomiar[10],Pomiar[11],Pomiar[12],Pomiar[13],Pomiar[14],Pomiar[15]);
        MessageLength = sprintf(DataToSend, "%d:%d:%d:%d\n\r", Pomiar[0],Pomiar[1],Pomiar[2],Pomiar[3]);
        CDC_Transmit_FS(DataToSend, MessageLength);

      //HAL_Delay(1);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

---

usart settings

```
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
    {
    
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 1 */
    // huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 1 */
  huart3.Instance = USART3;
 // huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 921600;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 2 */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` is very slow and you are sending ASCII 5 digits per ADC sample. You can send raw hex data 2 bytes per sample to save bandwidth like this

```
CDC_Transmit_FS(Pomiar, sizeof(Pomiar));
```